# How I can get a random value string in href by JSON Path Extractor with JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, href

I have `JSON` responce

```
{
    "sessionName":"eL7tYgxhYh",
    "imageSrc":"/Common/CaptchaImage/**eL7tYgxhYh**?t=636573960197174426"
}
```

How I can get a random value string `"eL7tYgxhYh"` in href by JSON Path Extractor with JMeter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot achieve this using JSON Extractor as it can only deal with [JSON Objects](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp), i.e. you can easily get full value of the `imageSrc` attribute, but not more.

I would recommend switching to [Boundary Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor) instead, the relevant configuration would be something like:

- Name of created variable: anything meaningful, i.e. `href`
- Left Boundary: `CaptchaImage/`
- Right Boundary: `?`

That's it, the "interesting" value should be now extracted and you should be able to refer it as `${href}` where required

Demo:

[image: JMeter Boundary Extractor Demo]

More information: [The Boundary Extractor vs. the Regular Expression Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter)

Answer (score 0):

JSON format is in key-value pair so you just need to mention the key for which you need to extract the value. As in your case, you can use following JSON path expression for fetching the text mentioned by you:

- $.sessionName

[image]

You can also use regular expression extractor which is another most important element of JMeter to extract the dynamic variables. Please refer to below blog of RedLine13 for more information on Regular Expressions:

https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/jmeter-extract-and-re-use-as-variable/

Let me know if you have any further question

Comment: But I only want to get string "eL7tYgxhYh" in imageSRC?
"imageSrc":"/Common/CaptchaImage/**eL7tYgxhYh**?t=636573960197174426"

Answer (score 0):

[image: jsonPath Extraction accessing AccessToken]

Above figure shows how to access access_token response of json and store it in access_token variable. In your case need to replace below.

JSONPath Expression use

```
  $..sessionName
```

Destination variable Name

```
  SessionName
```

[more information for accessing json path](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0??utm_source=BM&utm_medium=BM_blog&utm_campaign=jmeter-json-path-extractor-blog)

To Get  "636573960197174426"

To get required string from result string you can use BeanShell Assertion to split the string.

And Use link to fetch the vaiable properties and jmeter elements

[To Fetch jmeter Elements](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell)

[image: Split the String]

Comment: But I only want to get string "eL7tYgxhYh" in imageSRC?
"imageSrc":"/Common/CaptchaImage/**eL7tYgxhYh**?t=636573960197174426"

Comment: @user8800067 here  sessionName value is same as "eL7tYgxhYh" so if it is  same you can directly get from $..sessionName.

Comment: @user8800067 updated the answer for geeting the string value here to get t=636573960197174426 whole value need to split with '?' and to get    636573960197174426 need to split with '=' please refer updated answer.

Comment: @user8800067 welcome if your problem solved  please select correct sign on the left side under the answer.